# How to get the every 3rd date starting from the 0th one

Tags: python, list

I have the following data:

```
myList ['2016-01-01', '2016-02-05', '2016-03-04', '2016-04-01',
               '2016-05-06', '2016-06-03', '2016-07-01', '2016-08-05',
               '2016-09-02', '2016-10-07', '2016-11-04', '2016-12-02',
               '2017-01-06', '2017-02-03', '2017-03-03', '2017-04-07']
```

and I need to get the every 3rd date starting from the 0th one:

```
['2016-01-01', '2016-04-01', '2016-07-01', ...]
```

How can I do it in one line of code?

Of course I can do a for loop:

```
selected_dates = []
counter = 0
for d in dates:
   if counter >= 3:
      counter = 0
   # add a date
```

But is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Maybe go for list slicing? `myList[0::3]` It seems to be fastest way given your problem is just based on list and no other data manipulation is required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, there is indeed:

```
dates[0::3]
```